# pytables and pandas string padding question

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I've created a dataset using hdf5cpp library with a fixed size string (requirement). However when loading with pytables or pandas the strings are always represented like:

b'test\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff

The string value of 'test' with the padding after it. Does anyone know a way to suppress or not show this padding data? I really just want 'test' shown. I realise this may be correct behaviour.

My hdf5cpp setup for strings:

```
strType = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
status = H5Tset_size(strType, 36);
H5Tset_strpad(strType, H5T_STR_NULLTERM);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with your C Code. It is possible to work with padded strings in Pytables. I can read data written by a C application that creates a struct array of mixed types, including padded strings. (Note: there was an issue related to copying a NumPy struct array with padding. It was fixed in 3.5.0. Read this  for details: [PyTables GitHub Pull 720](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/pull/720).)

Here is an example that shows proper string handling with a file created by PyTables. Maybe it will help you investigate your problem. Checking the dataset's properties would be a good start.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty((10), 'S10')
arr[0]='test'
arr[1]='one'
arr[2]='two'
arr[3]='three'

with tb.File('SO_63184571.h5','w') as h5f:
    ds = h5f.create_array('/', 'testdata', obj=arr)
    print (ds.atom)
    
    for i in range(4):
        print (ds[i])
        print (ds[i].decode('utf-8'))
```

Example below added to demonstrate compound dataset with int and fixed string. This is called a `Table` in PyTables (Arrays always contain homogeneous values). This can be done a number of ways. I show the 2 methods I prefer:

1. Create a record array and reference with the `description=` or
   `obj=` parameter. This is useful when already have all of your data AND it will fit in memory.
2. Create a record array dtype and reference with the `description=`
   parameter. Then add the data with the `.append()` method. This is
   useful when all of your data will NOT fit in memory, OR you need to add data to an existing table.

Code below:

```
recarr_dtype = np.dtype( 
                { 'names':   ['ints', 'strs' ], 
                  'formats': [int, 'S10'] } )
a = np.arange(5)
b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) 
recarr = np.rec.fromarrays((a, b), dtype=recarr_dtype) 

with tb.File('SO_63184571.h5','w') as h5f:
    ds1 = h5f.create_table('/', 'compound_data1', description=recarr)
    
    for i in range(5):
        print (ds1[i]['ints'], ds1[i]['strs'].decode('utf-8'))

    ds2 = h5f.create_table('/', 'compound_data2', description=recarr_dtype)
    ds2.append(recarr)
    
    for i in range(5):
        print (ds2[i]['ints'], ds2[i]['strs'].decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible to post a compounded dataset containing  and int and a fixed string? I notice pytables adds a lot of structural additions..